# Sage installation failed on Ubuntu10.04

Tags: software-installation, 10.04, 32-bit, sagemath

I am trying to install `sage-6.4.1-x86_64-Linux` on my Ubuntu 10.04(32bit). But this installation failed:

[image]

How can I install it? Please help.

Comment: you have a 32bit system, and trying to install a 64bit package on it which is impossible!

Comment: @younes thank you for your kind respones. I shall download & install sage 32bit file.

Comment: @Fabby, yes chat

Comment: Site Crossposting is against the rules, by the way.

Comment: You also need to upgrade as 10.04 has been unsupported on the desktop since early 2013.

Comment: In case anyone runs across this, installing from source should also still work if you can get a recent enough gcc working on that old of an Ubuntu.

Answer (score 2):

Get the 32-bit installer from http://boxen.math.washington.edu/home/sagemath/sage-mirror/linux/32bit/index.html or another repository. You must install 32-bit apps only on a 32-bit operating system; the original install failed because you can't install 64-bit code on a 32-bit OS.